# Why ampersand in `std::is_member_function_pointer`?

Tags: c++, c++11, methods, member, type-traits

The example of use of `std::is_member_function_pointer` on [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_member_function_pointer) uses an ampersand and I have some difficulties to understand the syntax.

```
#include <type_traits>

class A {
    void member_function() { }
};

int main()
{
    // fails at compile time if A does not contain member_function as a function.
    static_assert(std::is_member_function_pointer<decltype(&A::member_function)>::value,
                  "Class does not contain member."); 
}
```

What is the meaning of `&A::member_function` and do `A::member_function` has a meaning (and if yes, what is the difference) ?

Furthermore, does `std::is_member_function_pointer` work with function templates ?

Comment: `A::member_function` doesn't have a meaning by itself, in an expression. The only way to form a pointer-to-member is `&ClassName::MemberName`.

Comment: `does std::is_member_function_pointer work with function templates?` I'm not sure I understand the question. `std::is_member_function_pointer` takes a type as its template parameter. A function template is not a type.

Comment: Note also that this use of `static_assert` is rather pointless. If `A` doesn't in fact contain a member named `member_function`, then that line of code is ill-formed, and the compiler will issue a syntax error, not the error message specified in `static_assert`. [Live example.](http://ideone.com/spavza) I suppose it would do something useful if `member_function` is in fact a data member.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik you're right, I changed the example a bit.

Comment: &A::member_function means you are passing a reference as an argument while A::member_function means you are just passing a value as an argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This expression

```
&A::member_function
```

literally means a member function pointer. The & is used to get the pointer.to a member function.

Comment: Pedantically, it's just a *pointer to member*. Whether it's a function member is secondary, and indeed part of the purpose of the OP's test.